# I want to get tweets but the object like Deffered object returns

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am writing CoffeeScript to get tweets from Twitter but something seems to be wrong...

```
class TwitterAPI
  getTweets: ->
    tweets_array = []
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=%40weed_7777')
    .done((data, status) ->
      $.each data.results, (i, item) ->
        tweets_array.push item.text

      return tweets_array
    )

twitter_api = new TwitterAPI
tweets = twitter_api.getTweets()
console.log tweets # returns object looks like Differed object
```

The content of `console.log tweets` is below:

[image]

What I want to do is get tweets as array.

Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: What's the point of writing Coffescript if it's not idiomatic? Your problem is indentation because the `return` (unnecesary) should be outside. Also even if you fix it, the array won't have the expected result because your code runs asynchronous, you'll get an empty array.

Comment: indentation is ok here, the main problem is not undestanding async stuff IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
getTweets = (callback) ->
  $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=%40weed_7777')
  .done (data) ->
    callback (i.text for i in data.results) 

getTweets (tweets) ->
  console.log tweets
```

As @elclanrs said, the http request is asynchronous, so you should pass a callback or use a deferred here. And IMO theres no need in class definition, because you dont store any state there.

BTW you can read some postings to deeper understand how async stuff works:

- http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101
- http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/asynchronous-javascript-the-tale-of-harry/
- http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/